# How to: material for custard ( preferably pap )

Tags: texturing, materials

The mesh is ready but all material combination I'm trying don't even come close to resemblance.

PS: is the content of the plate I'm trying to recreate.

Any help?
[image: pap but locally known as Akamu here in Nigeria]

Comment: Have you got the Mesh shape for the custard in the bowl and have you set up the lighting? If those are done then you just need to play with the Cycles nodes. How realistic do you want it? For instance, I can see some subtle colour changes in the custard. Try Mix node with a Glossy and BSDF Diffuse nodes.

Comment: Could you share the .blend file?

Comment: Yea, the mesh is ready. I'm still a newbie so my try out didn't work out so well.